# How to loop [('A', 1),('B', 2),('C', 4)] this type of data in graph ( django python)?

Tags: python, django

i want the result as below this code, here (A,1) A is the label and 1 is the data, so that I can present it in my graph, if you have any other solution to present this data [('A', 1),('B', 2),('C', 4)]  then please let me know,

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["A","B","C"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [1,2,4],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a dictionary.

Where `Label` is the Key and `Data` the value

```
yourDict = {
  "A": 1,
  "B": 2,
  "C": 4
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp